# App working in the background with GPS and how to stop it

Tags: ios, background, geolocation

I know that to make it possible for an app to continue working in the background its info.plist must include something like UIBackgroundModes with value 'location' (for example) to receive updates while in background.

What I'd like to do is an app that will continue to update the user location with the max precision, sending its coordinates to a website every 30 secs or more. All this while in the background.

First I'd like to know if this is possible, and if so, is there a way for the user to completely stop the app with a button? I mean, if the user opens up the app and then presses the home key, the app will continue in the background. But when he wants to stop it he should re-open it and then press a 'stop button' that will remove the background capability.

If all of this is possible, could I get some directions? Don't need code, just places where to get more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question:

> info.plist must include something like UIBackgroundModes with value 'location' (for example) to receive updates while in background

If that's not good enough, you can ask the OS to terminate your app when the user presses the Home button by setting a Boolean 'YES' value for the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in Info.plist.

Comment: And is it possible to change the info.plist programmatically from inside the app?